# Direct backup from Titanium Backup to DropBox

Tags: sync, dropbox, titanium-backup

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4, with root

I was wondering if it would be possible to make my backups straight to DropBox, without needing to save the files to my phone first. I had TiBu upload to DropBox after the backup, but TiBu cannot complete the backup because of the low disk space.

I was thinking of something like a symlink to DropBox, but I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. TiBu syncs a local copy to DropBox.

What you could do is:

- Use / Buy an external SD card (64GB or less)
- Go to `System settings`, open the Application manager, and `Move to SD card` TiBu

This way, it doesn't take up internal phone memory. (i.e. TiBu dumps its backup to the external SD card)